# c# EF view auto generated value in datagridview before insert

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-5

My datagridview loads data dynamically based on user selection. In my EDM, the columns with primary key have there store generated pattern set to identity, so I don't have any trouble inserting multiple rows. While inserting multiple rows, I see the ID column value as "0" in datagridview.Is it possible to view the generated value by databse in datagridview when I click on a cell? For example, in the attached image, f I type a new practice and click on division, then FILTER_ID will show the id generated by database. How can it be done?

Comment: Who is generating the ID? Is it you or the database?

Comment: Of course, the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have the ID before insert if you are generating it and instructing the database to store it as the ID. If the database is generating, the actual ID does not get generated until the insertion completes successfully. Thus there is no way for you to get the ID before insert.